# Neo4j - Create relationship between nodes based on property

Tags: neo4j

I have nodes in a graph. The nodes are of two types; lets call them `group a` and `group b`. I own a mapping of relationships between nodes in `group a` and `group b`, which are based on a `name` property in each node. For clarity, the mapping file looks somewhat like this:

```
(:a {name:'abc'})-[:RELATES_TO]->(:b {name:'def'}),
(:a {name:'abd'})-[:RELATES_TO]->(:b {name:'def'}),
...
(:a {name:'uvw'})-[:RELATES_TO]->(:b {name:'xyz'})
```

The `name` between groups is not shared, so I cannot use something like:

```
MATCH (a),(b)
WHERE a.name = b.name
MERGE (a)-[:RELATES_TO]->(b)
```

Since the existing nodes contain multiple properties, but the mapping only contains the `name` property, using the following `MERGE` results in the generation of new nodes, rather than the connecting of my existing nodes:

```
MERGE
(:a {name:'abc'})-[:RELATES_TO]->(:b {name:'def'}),
(:a {name:'abd'})-[:RELATES_TO]->(:b {name:'def'}),
...
(:a {name:'uvw'})-[:RELATES_TO]->(:b {name:'xyz'})
```

I believe could implement each relationship individually by manually adding the all properties to the mapping file and running the above merge, but I believe that all of the information to add the relationships already exists; I have both the start point and end point for each relationship. As a result, I suspect there must be a more elegant way to solve this problem.

It's been fairly ubiquitous in my past experience w/ Neo4j that the above problem occurs -> It's unclear to me whether I'm missing some syntax knowledge and this is an easy fix, or if I'm abusing the way Neo4j is intended to operate, and I need rethink how I'm proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be caused by the fact that you `MERGE` the entire pattern, which will cause the entire pattern to be created.
Assuming that the `name` properties serve as a unique key, I suggest you try this:

```
// make sure you have a list of a,b combinations, resulting from previous processing
a,b
'abc','def'
'abd','def'
...
'uvw','xyz''

// process these combinations
WITH a,b
MERGE (a:a {name:a})
MERGE (b:b {name:b})
MERGE (a)-[:RELATES_TO]->(b)
```

Note that creating a `CONSTRAINT` on the `name` property will sspeed things up.

Assuming you would have the names of the two sets of nodes in two different arrays, but which are of the same length, this would be a working example:

```
// these are the two arrays
WITH ['abc','abd','uvw'] AS aNodes, 
     ['def','def','xyz'] AS bNodes

// create an index for the array
UNWIND RANGE(0,size(aNodes)-1) AS i

//loop through the arrays to create a,b combinations
WITH aNodes[i] AS a,
     bNodes[i] AS b

// process these combinations
MERGE (n:a {name:a})
MERGE (m:b {name:b})
MERGE (n)-[:RELATES_TO]->(m)
RETURN *
```

Comment: When I try:
```
RETURN ['abc','abd','uvw'] AS a, ['def','def','xyz'] as b
with a,b
merge(a:a {name:a})
MERGE (b:b {name:b})
MERGE (a)-[:RELATES_TO]->(b)
```
I get an error that 'Variable `a` was already declared (line3)'

If I change to 
```
RETURN ['abc','abd','uvw'] AS x, ['def','def','xyz'] as y
with x,y
merge(a:a {name:x})
MERGE (b:b {name:y})
MERGE (a)-[:RELATES_TO]->(b)
```
I get the error that returns can only be used at the end of the statement. I'm not quite sure how to get the lists in place as you recommended (though I've read through the Neo4j doc on lists).

Comment: Replace your RETURN any WITH, then it should work

Comment: I see the logic of what you're recommending, and it makes sense, but I'm still getting an errors when I convert my RETURN to a WITH. It may be asking too much, but can you expand your answer into a simple working example that I can paste into the browser? I think what you're proposing sounds great, but I think I'm missing a bit of syntax.

Comment: @KeithLyons I expanded the answer, using your two arrays of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

#### First - create the nodes:

```
create
(:a {name:'abc'}),
(:a {name:'abd'}),
(:a {name:'uvw'}),
(:b {name:'def'}),
(:b {name:'def'}),
(:b {name:'xyz'})
```

#### Second - Enable Multi Statement Editor

Navigate to settings. Add check to `Enable multi statement query editor`

#### Third - Create Match/Merge Pairs for Each Relationship

The semicolon represents the end of a query. This is how you take advantage of the multi statement query editor.

```
match(a:a {name:'abc'}),(b:b {name:'def'})
merge(a)-[:RELATES_TO]->(b);
match(a:a {name:'abd'}),(b:b {name:'def'})
merge(a)-[:RELATES_TO]->(b);
match(a:a {name:'uvw'}),(b:b {name:'xyz'})
merge(a)-[:RELATES_TO]->(b);
```

Comment: ^^ Pointing out that this is a naive solution that I'm sharing only because it's the first thing that worked for me. This is not an industrial solution.